# Read data and print when not recognized

Tags: r

I am trying to print a line when my data finds a value that is different than expected. I can check for this, but I cannot figure out how to print the line it was found on, and the values of the variables associated to that specific line.

```
if(all(Cit1$State1 %in% ValidStates)==TRUE){
   cat("Success")} else
   {cat("State " State1 "is incorrect.\n")
   }
```

Calling out just the column name (State1 in this case) is a SAS technique. In this case, all I get is an error. Is there an equivalent for this in R?

Comment: `mtcars$gear[which(!(mtcars$gear %in% c(3, 4)))]`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at `Cit1$State1` and wanting to check if all values within that column are within the vector `ValidStates`, and print out the index and values of `Cit1` where this is not true, you could do this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Cit1)){
  if( !(Cit1$State1[i] %in% ValidStates) ){
    print(Cit1[i,])
  }
}
```

A full reproducible answer is found below.

```
ValidStates <- c("PA", "NY")
names <- c("Philadelphia", "New York", "Chicago")
State1 <- c("PA", "NY", "CH")
Cit1 <- data.frame(names, State1)

for(i in 1:nrow(Cit1)){
  if( !(Cit1$State1[i] %in% ValidStates) ){
    print(Cit1[i,])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for( i in 1:length(Cit1$State1))
  if(Cit1$State1[i] %in% lists) print("Success") else print(paste("State",Cit1$State1[i], "is wrong"))
```